# Is there a way to grow, slice and shrink byte buffers without reallocation in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management

I'm using `asyncio.StreamReader` to receive data from a remote source. This class has a [read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read) method which returns a `bytes` object.

Right now I use another `bytes` object to accumulate data I receive from the reader:

```
buffer_size = 128
buffer = b""
new_data = await stream_reader.read(buffer_size)

buffer += new_data
```

Then eventually I extract a payload message from the buffer, process it and get rid of the raw data from which the message was generated:

```
buffer = buffer[payload_length:]
```

There are multiple reallocations here, as `bytes` objects are immutable so every time I append something to the buffer the whole buffer is reallocated.

I understand that there's `bytearray`, but it's unclear which operations on it are mutating. Would

```
ba = bytearray()
ba += new_data
```

avoid any relocations?

Also, can I shrink a `bytearray` object while retaining its underlying memory buffer, similar to `std::vector.clear` in C++?

In general, what's the efficient way of manipulating byte buffers which minimises reallocation?

Comment: Simple answer: no.

Comment: This might be of use... https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews